# How to loop over a list of directories containing wildcards in bash?

Tags: bash, loops, wildcard

Assuming that I have a directory which contains decades of subdirectories:

```
$ ls -d /very/long/path/*/
adir1/ adir2/ b2dir/ b3dir/ k101/ k102/ k103/ k104/ k220/ k221/ k222/ etc
```

I would like to loop over a selection of directories which will be defined "dynamically" based on the answer given by the user and it will contain wildcards. For example (the code that doesn't work):

```
$ cat my_script.sh

DATADIR="/very/long/path"
echo -n "Select dirs to involve: "
read dirlist
for DIR in "$dirlist"; do
  echo $DATADIR/$DIR 
  [do stuff]
  ...
done
```

What would be desired is the following:

```
$ ./my_script.sh
Select dirs to involve: a* k10?

/very/long/path/adir1
/very/long/path/adir2
/very/long/path/k101
/very/long/path/k102
/very/long/path/k103
/very/long/path/k104
```

Any hint?

Comment: Your problem comes from the fact that your globbing expression is inside quotes, and quotes (single or double) prevent globbing from occurring.  Yet you cannot simply remove the quotes, as that could open the `$dirlist` expansion to word splitting, which you do not want to occur (i.e. paths containing spaces).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this would run into problems, but give it a whirl:

```
DATADIR="/very/long/path"

read -r -p "Select dirs to involve: " -a dirs

cd $DATADIR

for dir in ${dirs[@]}
do
    echo "$dir"
done
```

Leaving the array unquoted allows for the globs to expand.

UPDATE:  Dual loop to allow for using directory location

```
DATADIR="/very/long/path"

read -r -p "Select dirs to involve: " -a dirs

for item in "${dirs[@]}"
do
  for dir in "$DATADIR/"$item
  do
    echo "$dir"
  done
done
```

Comment: It works. However, I don't know how restrictive `cd` might be for further on

Comment: You can easily return to the previous location with cd -.  Otherwise you could place the items in curly braces separated by commas to get the same with location attached to the front.

Comment: without `cd` I can't pass `$DATADIR` to `echo` because with curly braces `$dirs` expansion splits and only the first item (i.e. `adir1, adir2`) is properly listed.

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution is to use `find` :

```
#!/bin/bash
DATADIR="/very/long/path"
echo -n "Select matching expression: "
IFS= read -r dirlist
while IFS read -r -d '' DIR; do
  echo "$DIR"
  [do stuff]
  ...
done < <(find "$DATADIR" -path "$dirlist" -print0)
```

I would advise that you read the manpage of `find`, as matching will eat up slashes, and might not behave as you are used to with shell globbing.

Please note that using the `-print0` and `read -d''` is a way to make sure files with funny names (whitespace, newlines) are handled without issues.

If you want to be able to handle several expressions input at the same time, you would have to do something like this :

```
#!/bin/bash
DATADIR="/very/long/path"
echo -n "Select matching expression: "
IFS= read -r -a dirlist_array
for dirlist in "${dirlist_array[@]}" ; do
  while IFS read -r -d '' DIR; do
    echo "$DIR"
    [do stuff]
    ...
  done < <(find "$DATADIR" -path "$dirlist" -print0)
done
```

Comment: `./my_script.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token <'` 
`./my_script.sh: line 9:   done < <(find "$DATADIR" -path "$dirlist" -print0)'`
Am I missing something?

Comment: @trian Strange, I checked it on shellcheck.net...  I would not have expected a problem like that.  Have you added any code in the inner loop?  Is your shell Bash, and if so, what version?

Comment: @trian It sounds like you're running the script with `sh scriptname`. If so, you should stop doing that (it's wrong because it can cause scripts to malfunction in bad ways). `./file` will automatically use the correct interpreter, or alternatively you can use `bash file` since the shebang says `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: @thatotherguy, @Fred,: This msg comes up because my shebang was `/bin/sh` (which is aliased to bash though). After I change it to `/bin/bash` I get: `IFS: command not found`

Comment: @trian This time it sounds like you wrote `IFS = read ...` instead of `IFS= read`. Please try copy-paste instead of writing freehand.

Comment: @thatotherguy I did copy-paste, in order to be at the safe side.